# How to Dump a locked PIC

Tags: memory-dump, copy-protection

I have tried these few days to read a PIC18F microcontroller which is locked.it says all protected (0000 E0FF 40FF).then i found out that it is possible to bypass the CRP on some of these microcontrollers by writing a small program into the bootloader (i think this is called heart of darkness) but didn't find that program to try to dump my PIC18F6722.
If someone knows a particular method to dumping firmware on this microchip please let me know
Thank you

Comment: Have you seen this article already? https://www.openpcd.org/images/HID-iCLASS-security.pdf